# How can I create suite/aggregate tests with pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

When I'm using tools like mocha/jasmine I can create a suite of tests which are aggregated by context. (with the describe keyword)

After I create a set/aggregation of tests I see it in the run results and I can run just a set of tests.

How can I achieve this with pytest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group tests with markers, that are similar to tags (or grep in jasmine)

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.webtest
def test_send_http():
    pass # perform some webtest test for your app
def test_something_quick():
    pass
def test_another():
    pass
class TestClass:
    def test_method(self):
        pass
```

and run with `pytest -v -m webtest`

other option is to group by class - one suite is one class and run this class with pytest

Comment: what are the -v -m flags?